# When should async await be used and when should then be used in flutter?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

Just kind of confused as to when I should use which? What are the differences?

Does `async await` not execute the next line of code in the function until done and does it get pulled out the general order of functions? If so what does `then` do, how does it differ?

If I wanted to make sure something was done before calling the method to get a value so it doesn't return a null which should I use?

For instance I wanted to get info from a database and then set a variable to that data as soon as the screen loads so i define that inside `initState()`,

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    currentUser= new User();
    currentUser.getInfo().then((_) =>setState(() { bio = currentUser.getBio(); print(bio); }));

  }
```

`getInfo` is an `async` fucntion, I tried this but what ends up happening is it somehow prints null first and then later prints the actual bio which is called from inside the getinfo method. How do I switch the order?

UPDATE:
Here is the user class:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class User {
final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  final _auth= FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

  String displayName;
  String email;
   String bio;
  String photoUrl;


  Future<void> getCurrentUser() async{
      try{
        final user= await _auth.currentUser();

        if(user!=null){
          loggedInUser=user;
          email=loggedInUser.email;
        }}
      catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
    }

    Future<void> getInfo() async {
        await getCurrentUser();

        DocumentReference documentReference =
        _firestore.collection("users").document("$email");
        documentReference.get().then((DocumentSnapshot datasnapshot) {
          if (datasnapshot.exists) {
            displayName=datasnapshot.data['displayName'].toString();
            bio=datasnapshot.data['bio'].toString();
            print(bio);
          }
          else {
            print("No such user");
          }

        });

      }

   User({String bio,String displayName}){
   if(bio!=null){
    this.bio= bio;
    print(this.bio);
   }
   if(displayName!=null){
   this.displayName = displayName;
}

   }


   void updateData({String bio, String displayName}){

   if(bio!=null){
    this.bio=bio;
    print(this.bio);
    }
    if(displayName!=null){
    this.displayName=displayName;
    }
   _firestore.collection('users').document('$email').setData({
   'bio':this.bio,
   'displayName':this.displayName
   });

}

    String getBio(){
    return bio;
    }
}
```

UPDATE :

changed getinfo to this and it worked now , dont really get why though:

```
 Future<void> getInfo() async {
        await getCurrentUser();

        DocumentReference documentReference =
        _firestore.collection("users").document("$email");
        await documentReference.get().then((DocumentSnapshot datasnapshot) {
          if (datasnapshot.exists) {
            displayName=datasnapshot.data['displayName'].toString();
            bio=datasnapshot.data['bio'].toString();
            print(bio);
          }
          else {
            print("No such user");
          }

        });

      }
```

Comment: post `User.getBio()` code (or even better the whole `User` class)

Comment: User.getBio() is really just a getter method, but i know that the way i got the  data works because the print statement inside getInfo prints out the actual value of bio but only AFTER the first print statement in initstate gets printed out as null

Comment: why do you mix `await` and `then` inside `getInfo` method? just be consistent and use `await` only

Comment: I'm not sure, i used await to wait for the getCurrentUser to finish so that i can use the email of the current user. How can i reformat this to just use 'then' ? Again i am not sure i even understand the difference that much but would changing this solve the issue?

Comment: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures#sequential-processing-async

Comment: Okay, but i cant do that in initstate since it cant be async..

Comment: change `getInfo` method so that it uses `await` only - you dont have to change anything in `initState`

Comment: now `getInfo` does not return any `Future` - thats why you have such strange nulls

Comment: The code i used in getinfo i found from online resources like the cloud firestore docs, they used then. I dont know if its possible to do the same thing and use await instead.

Comment: did you see the link i posted? https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures#sequential-processing-async ? just use `await expensiveA();
  await expensiveB();` - two `await`s in a row

Comment: Yea i saw it,thanks, i just didnt know how to get rid of the 'then' because the next parts depended on it and i dont know how to write them out without it. I added an await on there if you check the updated code and it worked i dont fully understand why if you care to explain. I thought initially, it would wait for getcurrentuser to finish and then the next lines would get the information and THEN set the values with it. Why did that not work without the extra await?

Comment: i already explained that: `"now getInfo does not return any Future - thats why you have such strange nulls"`

Comment: your code is still wrong: you use `then` which is not needed since you have `await` - read https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures#async-await on how to use `await`

Answer (score 1):

`await` is a keyword that can only be used in `async` method.

`then()` is a method.

---

Example:

```
Future<void> A() async {
  await Future.delayed(_duration);
  print("A");
}

void B() {
  print("B");
}

void C() {
  print("C");
}
```

with **await**

```
void withAwait() async {
  await A();
  B();
  C();
}
/// Print A, B, C respectively
```

with **then**

```
void withThen() {
  A().then((_) => B());
  C();
}
/// Print C, A, B respectively

void withThen2() {
  A().then((_) {
    B();
    C();
  });
}
/// Print A, B, C respectively
```